# Usando criptografia assimétrica entre Cliente Xamarin PCL e Web Api

Tags: c#, criptografia, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, rsa

Estou com certo problema em criar uma criptografia assimétrica entre meu App cliente usando Xamarin Forms (PCL) e o servidor (Web Api). Fiz usando simétrica e pediram para eu modificar.
Já faço tudo via SSL, mas mesmo assim querem a criptografia assimétrica para os dados na querystring e o resultado do json.

Minha dúvida é: Posso requisitar a chave pública ao servidor e passá-la via querystring normalmente para encriptar? 
Outra dúvida: Posso colocar uma chave privada fixa e ele criar a publica a partir dela ? Ou isso deixa vulnerável ?

Se alguém tiver algum exemplo utilizando PCLCrypto ou BouncyCastle para assimétrica, por favor postem aqui. Não consigo achar